# How to prove in ZF that every set has a transitive closure

Tags: set-theory

P Johnstone's "Notes on Logic and Set Theory" states that, for any set $x$, its transitive closure $\bigcup\{x\cup\bigcup x\cup\bigcup\bigcup x\cup\dots\}$ may be constructed using Union, Replacement, and Infinity.

How can this be proved? In particular, I don't see what *definable* function class to use in applying Replacement. (We can define informally that the ordinal 0 maps to $x$, 1 to $\bigcup x$, 2 to $\bigcup\bigcup x$, etc., but my understanding is that Replacement only applies if we can express the mapping as a function class, i.e. with a defined predicate.)

I don't want to use the Recursion Theorem, because the text uses transitive closure along the way in proving the recursion theorem.

Comment: You are going to have to appeal to the recursion theorem, one way or another. Might as well prove this specific instance of it, then the rest.

Comment: I voted to migrate this question to Math.SE, by the way. I think it's a better fit there.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila for taking a look. I'm happy for the question to be moved to Math.SE.

Comment: It should happen sometime soon, I hope. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the following function $F(n,x)=y$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_i$ for $i\leq n$ with $x_0=x$ and $x_n=y$, such that for all $i<n$, $x_{i+1}=\bigcup x_i$.

Prove that this is a function, and that it is well-defined for all $n<\omega$. Then appeal to Infinity, Replacement, and finally Union.

---

Another approach to do that is to appeal to the von Neumann hierarchy. Once you know that $x$ is a subset of *some* transitive set, you can just take the intersection of all transitive sets containing $x$ and prove that it is indeed the transitive closure of $x$.

If you're unhappy with applying the Recursion Theorem (for $\omega$), then you're likely to be unhappy with this solution either, as it requires transfinite recursion to define the von Neumann hierarchy.

Comment: +1. Yet another way: having established that every set has a rank, show that a set with no transitive closure has an element with no transitive closure.

Comment: @Anonymous: I am guessing that you downvoted this for using "too much Replacement", just let me point out that it *is* an axiom of ZF. The question wasn't about a minimal theory proving transitive closures exist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, that's not it. I would be surprised if there existed a proof which didn't rely on replacement. The reason for my downvote was when you said to "Prove that this is a function". The fact that $F$ exists (as a set) seems like a nontrival step to me (although I understand if you disagree). I think one would need to use a logical form of the recursion theorem or axiom of replacement with a complicated functional relation.

Comment: @Anonymous: I never wrote that $F$ is a set. It is not a set. What I do claim is that (1) if $n<\omega$, then $F(n,x)$ is uniquely determined. This is provable by a fairly simple (and internal) induction argument on the set $\omega$, and therefore we can declare $F(n,x)=\varnothing$ if $n\notin\omega$. I am not sure why this is so difficult, but fine: $F(0,x)=x$ by definition; if $F(n,x)$ is uniquely determined, then $F(n+1,x)=\bigcup F(n,x)$ by definition. Apply Union and Extensionality to obtain that this is also uniquely determined. What part is complicated?

Comment: @Anonymous: Applying Replacement, by the way, is done on $\omega$ by fixing $x$ as a parameter. Just to clarify the use of that axiom.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. I misinterpreted "function" as meaning "set function" (since that's my default interpretation of that word). Specifically, I assumed $F$ was meant to be a (set) function with domain $\omega\times\{x\}$ for fixed $x$ when applying replacement, but I see now that $F$ was simply meant to be the class function whose corresponding predicate is used in applying replacement. My mistake.