# A detailed proof for the existence of the transitive closure

Tags: set-theory

Is there a detailed and/or rigorous proof that the transitive closure of a set exists? I provide my own answer below, but I welcome any other proofs.

In [Existence of the transitive closure for sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284992/existence-of-the-transitive-closure-for-sets), [How to prove in ZF that every set has a transitive closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706215/how-to-prove-in-zf-that-every-set-has-a-transitive-closure/2706216#2706216), and [Using Replacement to prove transitive closure is a set without recursion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150467/using-replacement-to-prove-transitive-closure-is-a-set-without-recursion) users attempt to prove the existence of the transitive closure of a set in ZF. The proofs which involve the axiom of regularity use facts which typically assume the existence of transitive closures. The proofs which do not use the axiom of regularity attempt to use the recursion theorem or something similar, but they omit nontrivial steps. The versions of the recursion theorem I most often see are not strong enough to prove the existence of the transitive closure, so I think further explanation would be needed.

Comment: "Omit nontrivial steps" is kind of insulting, to be honest. Do you also expect me to develop forcing from scratch in every answer I post that involves forcing?

Comment: It's fine to post a question in order to answer it. But currently this looks more like an editorial column. Please edit this to look like an actual question.

Comment: While it is OK to answer your own question, and even to ask a question with the explicit purpose to answer it yourself (and I appreciate that you are forthright about this), I think that still it should remain in the question/answer format. I don't see any question here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed, I would not expect a development of forcing in every problem which uses it, but if standard formulations of forcing were not strong enough to prove a result, I would at least expect an explanation of the formulation of forcing being used. With regards to this problem, in the formulations/proofs of the recursion theorem I most often see, the iterated function is a set function, whereas here the iterated function is a class function ($F(x)=\cup x$). As such I was not content with answers that simply referred to the recursion theorem and stated the iterated (class) function.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I see what you mean. I'll edit my question to match this format. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Can we make the part that is an actual question clear, separate, and perhaps at the start of the post, rather than having a preamble about how all those other users are using the axioms of ZF unnecessarily?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure thing. Although let me clarify that using axioms of ZF wasn't my issue. It was the use of theorems which would have made the argument circular or making arguments which appeared to make unjustified assumptions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not 100% sure but I think there are some problems with the answer; i wrote a comment underneath the answer but I thought to check with you since you’re an expert in set theory…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the fact that $\omega$ exists and satisfies induction, which follows from the axiom of infinity and specification. Note that I do not use the axiom of regularity which means that this proof is valid in ZF without regularity. I avoid using the recursion theorem here, although a logical form of the recursion theorem could be used to give an alternative proof.

Let $s$ be a fixed set. First, we wish to prove the existence of the set $\{s,\cup s,\cup\cup s,\ldots\}$. We define some notational shortcuts.

$$\text{Func}(f)=\forall p(p\in f\Rightarrow \exists x\exists y[p=(x,y)])\land\forall x\forall y\forall z([(x,y)\in f\wedge(x,z)\in f]\Rightarrow y=z)$$

This simply says that $f$ is a function on some domain.

$$\text{Rec}(f)=\forall n\forall y((n,y)\in f\Rightarrow$$

$$[(n=0\wedge y=s)\vee(\exists m\exists z[m\in\omega\wedge n=m+1\wedge y=\cup z\wedge(m,z)\in f])])$$

This says that $f(0)=s$ and $f(m+1)=\cup f(m)$ whenever $m+1$ is in the domain of $f$. Note also that, if $f$ is a function, then $\text{Rec}(f)$ implies that the domain of $f$ is a subset of $\omega$. Finally, we have

$$\varphi(n,y)=\exists f(\text{Func}(f)\wedge\text{Rec}(f)\wedge(n,y)\in f)$$
We will use $\varphi$ with the axiom schema of replacement to obtain the set $\{s,\cup s,\cup\cup s,\ldots\}$. First, we must show that $\varphi$ is a functional relation (more formally, we want to prove $\forall n\in\omega\exists!y\varphi(n,y)$).

We proceed by induction. We see immediately that $\varphi(0,s)$ is true since $f=\{(0,s)\}$ is a function which satisfies $\text{Rec}(f)$. Suppose $\varphi(0,y)$. Then there exists a function $g$ such that $\text{Rec}(g)$ and $g(0)=y$. Because, $\text{Rec}(g)$ is true and there does not exist $m\in\omega$ such that $0=m+1$, we must have $y=s$.

Now let $n\in\omega$ and suppose there exists a unique $y$ such that $\varphi(n,y)$. Suppose that $\varphi(n+1,v)$ is true. Then there exists a function $g$ such that $\text{Rec}(g)$ and $(n+1,v)\in g$. Because $\text{Rec}(g)$ and $n+1\neq 0$, there exists $u$ such that $v=\cup u$ and $(n,u)\in g$ so that $\varphi(n,u)$. By the inductive hypothesis, this implies $u=y$ and hence $v=\cup y$. So, $v$ is unique, if it exists. Since $\varphi(n,y)$, there exists a function $f$ such that $\text{Rec}(f)$ and $(n,y)\in f$. Note that $n+1$ may or may not be in the domain of $f$. Let $f'=f\cup\{(n+1,\cup y)\}$. I claim $f'$ is a function such that $\text{Rec}(f)$. If $(n+1,w)\in f$ then $\varphi(n+1,w)$ which implies $w=\cup y$ by uniqueness. It then follows that $f'$ is a function since $f$ is. Now suppose $(n',y')\in f'$. If $n'\neq n+1$, then $(n',y')\in f$ so that either $n'=0$ and $y'=s$ or there exists $m'$ and $z'$ such that $n'=m'+1$, $y'=\cup z'$, and $(m',z')\in f\subset f'$. If $n'=n+1$, then this still holds since $y'=\cup y$ and $(n,y)\in f'$. Thus, $\text{Rec}(f)$ is true and hence $\varphi(n+1,\cup y)$ is true.

So, by induction, for every $n\in\omega$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $\varphi(n,y)$. Then, by the axiom schema of replacement, there exists a set $S$ such that $y\in S$ if and only if there exists $n\in\omega$ such that $\varphi(n,y)$ (i.e. $S=\{s,\cup s,\cup\cup s,\ldots\}$). Let $T=\cup S$. I claim that $T$ is the transitive closure of $s$.

First note that $s\in S$ since $\varphi(0,s)$, which implies $s\subset T$. Let $x_1\in x_2\in T$. Then there exists $y\in S$ such that $x_2\in y$. So, by the construction of $S$, there exists $n\in\omega$ such that $\varphi(n,y)$. Then, by the same reasoning as before, $\varphi(n+1,\cup y)$ so that $\cup y\in S$. However, since $x_1\in x_2\in y$, we know $x_1\in\cup y$ and hence $x_1\in T$. So, $T$ is transitive.

Suppose $T'$ is a transitive set containing $s$ and assume $T\not\subset T'$. Then $$A=\{n\in\omega:\exists x\exists y(x\in y\wedge\varphi(n,y)\wedge x\notin T')\}$$ is nonempty and therefore has a minimum element, $n_{min}$, by the well-ordering principle. Let $x$ and $y$ be such that $x\in y$, $\varphi(n_{min},y)$, and $x\notin T'$. Since $\varphi(n_{min},y)$, there exists a function $f$ such that $\text{Rec}(f)$ and $(n_{min},y)\in f$. If $n_{min}=0$ then $y=s$ and hence $s\not\subset T'$, a contradiction. If $n_{min}\neq 0$, then there exists $z$ and $m\in\omega$ such that $n_{min}=m+1$, $y=\cup z$, and $(m,z)\in f$ so that $\varphi(m,z)$. Since $x\in y=\cup z$, there exists $w\in z$ such that $x\in w$. Note that $w\notin T'$ since otherwise, we would have $x\in T'$ by transitivity. Thus, we see $w\in z$, $\varphi(m,z)$, and $w\notin T'$. So $m\in A$ and $m<n_{min}$, a contradiction. Hence, by way of contradiction, $T\subset T'$. This proves that $T$ is the transitive closure of $s$. The uniqueness of $T$ follows from the fact the minimality of the transitive closure under the subset relation.

Comment: If $Rec(f)$ is true then isnt $f$ already a function?

Comment: Assuming $f$ is a set of ordered pairs. Also i dont think the def'n of a function is correct since according to this defintion vacously {1} is a function

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku You're very right! I neglected to include in the definition of $\text{Func}(f)$ that the elements of $f$ are all ordered pairs. And you're right that what is written there is already implied by $\text{Rec}$, but I will leave that part as is. Thanks for the observation.